# In firebase searching main collection using sub collection reference

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We have a collection called `customer` that has all the details and another collection called `merchant` with a sub-sub-collection called merchant customers where we are paginating the customers.

We need to search the customer using the main customer document fields with pagination using the reference from merchant sub-collection.

**Customer Main records**
[image: Customer Records]

**Sub-Sub-collection**
[image]

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it, and indicate the exact data you ant to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore queries can only filter (and thus also only paginate) on values that  are present in the documents that it returns. There is no way to filer a document on values from somewhere else in the database.

So to allow the use-case, you will either have to replicate the relevant information from the subcollection into the main customer document, or replicate the information from the main customer document into the documents in the subcollection and then query that.